# Using VBA/VlookUp to use data from one table to match data in another table and use that to calculate quantity

Tags: excel, vba

[image][image]So I am working on an inventory spreadsheet and it basically has two large tables in it. One of the tables has the part number/description/location/lot number/quantity/etc (called "Inventory List") and the other one just has part number/description/vendor/total quantity (called "Ordering List"). The first table is mainly for tracking lot numbers of each item so it has multiple instances of one SKU/part number, while the second table is more used to track total quantity of each item for reordering purposes so it will just have one instance of each part number. The tables are locked to the user and the user edits the table by using a User Form to "Pick and Place" items into the table. Currently the pick button is set so they choose from the Lot number table and it will subtract the number they are taking out of or adding to inventory from that row, my question is, how do I match that part number selected in the first table to also subtract/add from/to the total quantity in the second table? I am very new to VBA, and I am not sure if this is even possible. The item that both tables have in common is the first column of each lists the part number. I can post the current code written for the pick/place buttons below.

```
Private Sub btnPick_Click()

    Dim pickValue As Integer
    Dim updateQTY As Integer
    Dim invQTY As Integer
    Dim findMe As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory List")

    If Selected_List = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You must select an Inventory Item Prior to Pick!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Edit"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.txtPPQty.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a quantity to pick.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Edit"
        Exit Sub
    End If

        pickValue = Me.txtPPQty.Value
        invQTY = Me.lstInventory.List(Me.lstInventory.ListIndex, 7)
        findMe = Selected_List + 4

    If pickValue > invQTY Then
        MsgBox "The pick quantity is too high!  Please select a lower Value.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Edit"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If pickValue <= invQTY Then
        updateQTY = invQTY - pickValue
    End If

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory List").Cells(findMe, 9) = updateQTY

   MsgBox "You have removed " + CStr(pickValue) + " units from the selected item.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Edit"
```

```
Dim pickValue As Integer
    Dim updateQTY As Integer
    Dim invQTY As Integer
    Dim findMe As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory List")

    If Selected_List = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You must select an Inventory Item to Return!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Edit"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.txtPPQty.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a quantity to Return.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Edit"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    pickValue = Me.txtPPQty.Value
    invQTY = Me.lstInventory.List(Me.lstInventory.ListIndex, 7)
    findMe = Selected_List + 4

    If pickValue > invQTY Then
        MsgBox "The pick quantity is too high!  Please use Inventory Edit functions.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Edit"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If pickValue <= invQTY Then
        updateQTY = invQTY + pickValue
    End If

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory List").Cells(findMe, 9) = updateQTY

    MsgBox "You have added " + CStr(pickValue) + " Units to the selected Item.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Edit"


End Sub
```

Comment: Could you upload screen shots of your worksheets or send me the worksheets?

Comment: If I am not mistaken you would just use `.Find` to find the relevant part number in the second table, and then use `.Offset` to adjust the relevant quantity?

Comment: Hi Dean, I am sorry, I am very new to VBA, you are probably right but would you mind going a little further into your explanation?

Comment: If I didn't originally make it clear, these tables are in two separate sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I have tried to create a general routine to demonstrate my suggested solution. It is by no means the most efficient, but it should complete the task you are after.

First, some clarifications. The routine takes two arguments, `part_number` and `order_qty`. The `order_qty` is the new quantity of the part number you want to set in the other table.

Second, I have used general declarations for demonstrative purposes, so you can adjust these where necessary for your case.

Third, `quantity_offset` is the column offset from the `Part Number` column to the `Total Quantity` column.

Here is the code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Update_Quantity(part_number As String, order_qty As Long)

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, update_table_name As String, column_header As String
    Dim rng_part_number As Range
    Dim quantity_offset As Long


    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Update_Sheet")
    update_table_name = "myTable"
    column_header = "Part Number"
    quantity_offset = 10


    'find part number
    'assuming table object and column header Part Number
    Set rng_part_number = ws1.Range(update_table_name & "[" & column_header & "]").Find(What:=part_number, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    'assign new qty
    rng_part_number.Offset(0, quantity_offset).Value = order_qty

End Sub
```

Comment: This is very helpful and I am working to implement this into my code right now. Just one question, why is quantity_offset set to 10?

Comment: @Julia that was a random number I chose. Change it for your purpose.